# Django, how to template aggregate responses

Tags: python, django

I have series of aggregations in DJANGO that I am performing.  What I want to know, is if there is a way to {{ template }} a particular row-value from a dataset.

For example:  If I have this dataset response from the server:

```
[{ type:'O', count:54},{ type:'E', count:125},{ type:'C', count:2}]
```

Can I reference the counts by type in the template without going through the foreach command?

For example:  officers: {{ variable.O.count }} or something like that so I can just directly reference the value in a specific row?

The only other option I have right now, is to call the database three times.  And I'm hoping not to have to do that.

Thank you.

Comment: Why don't you send the data back in a more useful format? A single dict keyed by type value would allow you to do what you want: `{ 'O': 54, 'E': 125...}`.

Comment: ok.  either way, How do I get 54, when I want it, without having to go through the for loops?